# how to split a string to multiply each single number by a value in ms access 2007

Tags: vba, ms-access

I need to split a string of 20 digits individually and multiply each single one by a value.

```
String (this string is in a text box) example: 11604999123400002586
```

After the split, I must do the following operation:

```
51 x 1º digit +
73 x 2º digit +
17 x 3º digit +
89 x 4º digit +
38 x 5º digit +
62 x 6º digit +
45 x 7º digit +
53 x 8º digit +
15 x 9º digit +
50 x 10º digit +
5 x 11º digit +
49 x 12º digit +
34 x 13º digit +
81 x 14º digit +
76 x 15º digit +
27 x 16º digit +
90 x 17º digit +
9 x 18º digit +
30 x 19º digit +
3 x 20º digit
```

**In this example:**

```
Result = 51x1 + 73x1 + 17x6 + 89x0 + 38x4 + 62x9 +
45x9 + 53x9 + 15x1 + 50x2 + 5x3 + 49x4 + 34x0 + 81x0 + 76x0 + 27x0 + 90x2
+ 9x5 + 30x8 + 3x6 = 2627
```

What would be the best way to do it?

Comment: Where do the multipliers `51, 73, 17...` come from?

Comment: The multipliers are always the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In VBA you can do something like this:

```
Dim a(20) as Integer
a(1) = 51
a(2) = 73
…
a(20) = 3

Dim Result AS Long: Result = 0
For i = 1 to 20
    Result = Result + CInt(Mid(MyString,i,1)) * a(i)
  Next i
```

Comment: Actually a will have values from a(0) all the way to a(20). a(0) is just not being used. I chose to make the code simpler and more readable, rather than use one less int worth of RAM.

Comment: Sorry I didn't realize that.  Nice.

Comment: To be honest I had to check and double check when I saw that, because in every other language a declaration of an array with `20` would indeed have 20 values from 0 to 19. It seems to be a unique VBA peculiarity.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with SQL.
Create a table, say with name `weights`, with 2 columns:

```
id:     Number
weight: Number
```

and insert these rows:

```
id  weight
1   51
2   73
3   17
4   89
5   38
6   62
7   45
8   53
9   15
10  50
11  5
12  49
13  34
14  81
15  76
16  27
17  90
18  9
19  30
20  3
```

Then execute this query:

```
SELECT SUM(w.weight * val(mid('11604999123400002586', w.id, 1))) AS result 
FROM weights AS w
```

Result:

```
2627
```

Comment: I cannot store those numbers. The string is generated by each quote. I have dozzens of quotes by client.

Comment: Somehow you have to order these numbers, because the order is important so to multiply each of them with a digit in a specific position of the string, right? So you have to store them, if not in a table then in a structure like an array and create a function by VBA code to get the result.

Answer (score 1):

Consistency of structure is critical in string manipulation. Assume there will always be 20 digits in string and every record will have value.

Calculate 20 columns and add them together for the Total - here are 2:

`SELECT Quotes.*, Mid([Data],1,1)*53 AS A, Mid([Data],2,1)*71 AS B, [A]+[B] AS Total FROM Quotes;`

Could pull weight factor from table. DLookup is one way but domain aggregate can cause slow performance in large dataset so if weight factors will never change, probably don't want this:

`SELECT Quotes.Data, Mid([Data],1,1)* DLookup("Weight","Factors","ID=1") AS A, Mid([Data],2,1)* DLookup("Weight","Factors","ID=2") AS B, [A]+[B] AS Total FROM Quotes;`

A Cartesian relationship with aggregate calcs query using data and weight factors tables can calculate Total - Cartesian can also perform slowly with large dataset:

```
SELECT Quotes.ID, Sum(Mid([Data],[Factors].[ID],1)*[Weight]) AS Total
FROM Factors, Quotes
GROUP BY Quotes.ID;
```

A custom VBA function could return just the total. Call this function from query or textbox. The weight factors can be pulled from table or hard coded in an array construct.

```
Function GetTotal(strD) As Long
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset, x As Integer
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT Weight FROM Factors ORDER BY ID")
For x = 1 To 20
    GetTotal = GetTotal + Mid(strD, x, 1) * rs!Weight
    rs.MoveNext
Next
End Function
```